# Windows Azure Emulator Needs Constant Resetting

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, azure-compute-emulator

I have a problem where SQL Server isn't playing with with the Azure Development Storage.

When I start debugging I always have to run the DSInit command. It runs successfully with the following output:

```
Added reservation for http://127.0.0.1:10000/ in user account STARDESTROYER\NW.
Added reservation for http://127.0.0.1:10001/ in user account STARDESTROYER\NW.
Added reservation for http://127.0.0.1:10002/ in user account STARDESTROYER\NW.

Found SQL Instance (localdb)\v11.0.
Creating database DevelopmentStorageDb20 on SQL instance '(localdb)\v11.0'.

Granting database access to user STARDESTROYER\NW.
Database access for user STARDESTROYER\NW was granted.

Initialization successful. The storage emulator is now ready for use.
```

However after a few minutes I start getting this error pop up for SQL Server:

`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.`

I can dismiss the popup, and debugging works fine, but I'll keep getting the popup repeatedly, every minute or so. It's really annoying and I usually just move the popup off the edge of my screen.

If I close the Azure emulator then the popups can finally be dismissed, but if I want to debug again I have to start back with another DSInit command.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the Windows Azure SDK and is there a version of SQL Server installed on the workstation (the DSInit is using localdb, an in process SQL Express)?

Comment: Yes I did try re-installing the Azure SDK. I have SQL Server installed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be an issue with the localdb (SQL Express).  Since you have a full SQL Server instance also on the machine try running DSInit to set up the devstore on it.

You can use the /server or /instance parameters to specify you want to use a specific SQL Instance.  Try running using a full SQL Server as the backend for the storage emulator.

Comment: Thanks so much - that totally did it I just ran DSInit /server:STARDESTROYER and it worked perfectly. I didn't realize Azure was pointing to SQLExpress